# Example of application covered with tests

Tags: unit-testing, download, integration-testing

is there sample/open_source application for download that is covered with tests(integration, unit, ...) and could be example how testing should be done? We want to learn our junior programmers how tests should be written(ok ok, and we(seniors) want to learn, too :))

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at public metrics of sonar. It scans a lot of open-source projects. Just pick the ones with the highest coverage ;)

[Coverage list open-source projects](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/?asc=false&sort=5)

Answer (score 3):

I would bet the JUnit framework is well covered with unit tests :-)

You can download the sources from [here](http://github.com/KentBeck/junit/downloads) .